# Keyframes for animating SVG path using transform: translate not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, transform, keyframe

Hey i'm trying to make a fancy border animation around some words and it's working well in Firefox & Chrome but not in IE. I was wondering if somebody knew why it isnt working in IE? The animation won't initiate.

My HTML

```
<div class="box">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="top" x1="-146" y2="0" x2="400" y2="0" />
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="60" x2="0" y2="-30" />
    <line class="bottom" x1="292" y1="30" x2="-264" y2="30" />
    <line class="right" x1="146" y1="-30" x2="146" y2="60" />
</svg>
 <h2>My Words</h2>
```

My CSS

```
h2 {
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
color: black;
letter-spacing: 0.07em;
}

.box {
width: 146px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
color: #2c3e50;
padding-bottom: 0.05em;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 0.05em;
}

.box svg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.box svg line {
stroke-width: 3;
stroke: #000;
fill: none;
}

.box svg line.top, .box svg line.bottom, .box svg line.left, .box svg line.right {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s !important;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.25s !important;
-ms-animation-delay: 0.25s !important;
-o-animation-delay: 0.25s !important;
animation-delay: 0.25s !important;
}

.box svg line.top {
stroke-dasharray: 146;
-webkit-animation: Topline 1s;
-moz-animation: Topline 1s;
-ms-animation: Topline 1s;
-o-animation: Topline 1s;
animation: Topline 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box svg line.bottom {
stroke-dasharray: 146;
-webkit-animation: Bottomline 1s;
-moz-animation: Bottomline 1s;
-ms-animation: Bottomline 1s;
-o-animation: Bottomline 1s;
animation: Bottomline 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box svg line.left {
stroke-dasharray: 30;
-webkit-animation: Leftline 1s;
-moz-animation: Leftline 1s;
-ms-animation: Leftline 1s;
-o-animation: Leftline 1s;
animation: Leftline 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box svg line.right {
stroke-dasharray: 30;
-webkit-animation: Rightline 1s;
-moz-animation: Rightline 1s;
-ms-animation: Rightline 1s;
-o-animation: Rightline 1s;
animation: Rightline 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Topline {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-146px);
}
}

@keyframes Topline {
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-146px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-146px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-146px);
    transform: translateX(-146px);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes Bottomline {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(146px);
}
}

@keyframes Bottomline {
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(146px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(146px);
    -o-transform: translateX(146px);
    transform: translateX(146px);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes Leftline {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
}
}

@keyframes Leftline {
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
    -o-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes Rightline {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
}
}

@keyframes Rightline {
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}
}
```

Here is a setup of what i'm trying to accomplish : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPs2B/4/)

And [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css/) is the demo that I roughly followed.